# Separation of concerns in angular - passing functions to directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are always told to ensure proper separation of concerns ([How do I “think in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)), and that the view should be the official record of what is going on.

Suppose we have a directive that dynamically the src of an element based on a separate function. I was under the impression that we should pass in a function to the directive using an isolate scope and '&'.

However, does this count as not separating concerns since the view now contains logic? Or is it okay because myFunction() is stored in the controller?

```
<img my-src callback='myFunction()' />
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app='testApp'>
    <div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
        <img my-src callback='myFunction()' />
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
        return 'http://nodejs.org/images/roadshow-promo.png';
    }
})
.directive('mySrc', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            callback: '&'
        },
        link: function ( scope, elem, attrs ) {
            elem.attr('src', scope.callback());
        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks fine, the controller is still in control what the view shows... But if it's really only setting the src dynamically, you could use ng-src.

```
<img ng-src="{{ myFunction() }}" />
```

Example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Rw2OG1ltrmpUO2oLO1fE?p=preview